# Image not displayed with clarity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using auto layout and working with custom `UITableViewCell`. Inside this cell, I want tp display an image. Issue is that image is not displayed with clarity.

Actual image is this :

[image]

But in app, it is displayed as below :

[image]

What can be the reason? How to solve it?

![enter image description here][3]

Comment: Could you give code that set image to the cell?

Comment: try setting the shouldRasterize property to YES.
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

Comment: @nmh I just set image in storyboard. Only code I was using is mentioned in my updated question.

Comment: @YoCoh Did not work. I could make it look better. Please see my updated question

Comment: what is the problem, really? the image has been scaled to fit in your case as usual. that procedure obviously distorts your image, because the _acpect ratio_ has been changed. therefore the original corner could not be the same on the distorted image... regarding the green gradient, you can resolve that isuse with using two different 'layers' (not _such_ layer!), 1. a static image of the green gradient, and 2. a strechable image of the frame only with rounded corners... and problem would be solved in 10 mins (even if you would strech the gradient the final result will be accepptable entirely).

Comment: regarding the new issue, I would use resizableImageWithCapInsets. Here are few good articles:  http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/07/05/customizing-appearance-with-resizable-images.html   &    http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/12/20/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets/

Comment: @YoCoh `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` solved the issu. You can post this as an answer.

Comment: @Geek good luck on your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain corner radius for changes in image dimensions, use the `resizableImageWithCapInsets` method on `UIImage`.

Good tutorials:

1. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/07/05/customizing-appearance-with-resizable-images.html
2. http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/12/20/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets/